# Angular 2 - Removing a Validator error

Tags: forms, angular, validation

I wrote a function to update Validator rules on an input if a certain option was selected, using this method (the forms are built using FormGroup):

```
onValueChanged(data : any) {
    let appVIP1 = this.vip1TabForm.get('option1');
    let appVIP2 = this.vip2TabForm.get('option2');
    let appVIP3 = this.vip3TabForm.get('option3');

    //Set required validation if data is 'option3'
    if(data != 'option3') {
        //Due to initialization errors in UI, need to start with the case
        //That there are validations, check to remove them
        appVIP1.setValidators([]);
        appVIP2.setValidators([]);
        appVIP3.setValidators([]);
    }
    else {
        appVIP1.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        appVIP2.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        appVIP3.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    }
}
```

And I bind that function call to a click event on radio buttons (I initially used the guide from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40886324/angular2-conditional-required-validation), but the onChange function didn't bind correctly).

This works great, and if the user selects option 1 or 2, the validations are empty, and won't be triggered.  If they select option 3, the validations are shown and submission is stopped.  However, I run into the problem where the user submits, sees the error, and goes back to change to option 1 or 2.  While the validator is cleared, my form still reads as invalid.  I have multiple input fields I am validating, so I can't just set the form to valid if the validator is removed this way.  How would I go about doing this?  Can I remove the `has-error` for one particular field in the formgroup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the correct validators are in place, you can [manually call `AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#updateValueAndValidity-anchor) after they select an option:

```
this.formBuilder.updateValueAndValidity();
```

(Where, of course, `this.formBuilder` is your `FormBuilder` instance.)

You can also call it on FormElements directly.

This is commonly used to trigger validation after a form element's value has been programmatically changed.

Comment: ...It's, uhhh, even there in the link I showed... let's pretend I never asked this question :) . I'll update this question as your answer when I test it and it works (I'm sure it will).

Comment: @user3334871 No problem, angular is a huge framework and it takes a while to figure it all out. This came to mind because I needed to make _heavy_ use of it in a recent (very similar) application. Out of curiosity, try it just on a `FormGroup` (never tried, can't right now) rather than the whole `FormBuilder`; curious if that works, too.

Comment: Sure!  I'll post my result in a second after my build and deploy

Comment: Hey!  Just to give an update!  So, calling `updateValueAndValidity()` on the FormGroup or FormBuilder didn't work.  What I did was call it on my input objects, so it would be `appVIP1.updateValueAndValidity();` that worked.  I will still mark this as the answer, but you can also update it to include what worked for me :)

Comment: @user3334871 Glad to hear it! Will do and thanks for the update. For the record, I do call it on the FormBuilder directly...I sure hope it actually does what I think it does.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of removing and adding validations. It is more simple to enable and disable fields. You need to add the Validators.required for all required fields. And disable the fields which are not required.

```
onValueChanged(data : any) {
    let appVIP1 = this.vip1TabForm.get('option1');
    let appVIP2 = this.vip2TabForm.get('option2');
    let appVIP3 = this.vip3TabForm.get('option3');

    if(data != 'option3') {
        appVIP1.disable();
        appVIP2.disable();
        appVIP3.disable();
    }
    else {
        appVIP1.enable();
        appVIP2.enable();
        appVIP3.enable();
    }
}
```