# Access another form within a Validator in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-forms

I would like to validate if two forms have the same content using Angular 2 validators. How can I access the value of one form from the validator function of another form?

Suppose I created the form like this:

```
let registerForm = formBuilder.group({
    field1: [''],
    field2: ['',  sameThanfield1],
});
```

sameThanfield1() being a validator function containing this code, which wont work though, because I dont have access to the value of another form. How can I solve this?

```
sameThanfield1(form: FormControl): any {

   if(form.field1 !== form.field2) {
        return {
            "not the same": true
        };
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at an answer I gave to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204812/angular2-forms-validator-with-interrelated-fields/40416197#40416197)... It is a bit long winded but it is the best reusable way to achieve this IMO.

Comment: To clarify this question's title - in your code, it looks like you have only *one form*, but two different controls. Validating between two forms would be much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to validate if two fields have the same value.

You can access specific control's value.
I'll assume that your validator is in the same scope as the form object.

```
@Component({
// ...
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

    registerForm: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.registerForm = formBuilder.group({
            field1: [''],
            field2: ['', this.sameAsField1],
        });
    }

    sameAsField1(control: formControl) {

        if (this.registerForm && control.value === this.registerForm['field1'].value) {
            return {
                "not the same": true
            };
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me: "EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'registerForm' of undefined"

Comment: Validator is executed when the form is undefined. Updated the code.

Comment: Also this return an exception: 'Cannot read property 'registerForm' of undefined'

Comment: This solution looks useful, but it's missing a proper `this` bind when setting up the `sameAsField` function. It should probably be: `field2: ['', control => this.sameAsField1(control)]` as the easiest way of preserving it (as lambda calls will preserve that context)

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, however without validators. It monitors the **valueChanges Observable**.

```
@Component({
// ...
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

registerForm: any;
passError: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        field1: [''],
        field2: ['', this.sameAsField1],
    });

    this.registerForm.valueChanges.subscribe(function (){
      if(this.registerForm.value.field1 !== this.registerForm.value.field2) passError = true;
    });

}
```

}